# Using Tweepy API behind proxy

Tags: python, oauth, proxy, tweepy

I have a using **Tweepy**, a python wrapper for Twitter.I am writing a small GUI application in Python which updates my twitter account.

Currently, I am just testing if the I can get connected to Twitter, hence used test() call. I am behind Squid Proxy server.What changes should I make to snippet so that I should get my work done.

Setting **http_proxy** in bash shell did not help me.

```
def printTweet(self):
    #extract tweet string
    tweet_str = str(self.ui.tweet_txt.toPlainText()) ;
    #tweet string extracted.
    self.ui.tweet_txt.clear()  ;

    self.tweet_on_twitter(str);

def tweet_on_twitter(self,my_tweet) :
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
    auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET) ;
    api = tweepy.API(auth) ;

    if api.test() :
        print 'Test successful' ;
    else :
        print 'Test unsuccessful';
```

Comment: Semicolons *are not needed* in python, you can remove them all.

Comment: Yes Sir, but I _like_ using semi colons. Help ON topic needed :)

Comment: You'll be lonely..

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should set 'https_proxy' instead.

On my linux, I use this:

```
> export HTTPS_PROXY="http://xxxx:8888"
```

before running my Tweepy script.

Tweep uses 'requests' package for sending request, read http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies for more.

Comment: Why is your `export` line commented out? That actually suggests you are *not* using it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I just changed "#" to ">".

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: Turns out this isn't a viable answer, but I'm leaving it here for reference**

---

Since a quick glance of the code shows that tweepy is using urllib2.urlopen & co., the easiest  is possibly to just override the default opener...

```
# 'x.x.x.x' = IP of squid server
your_squid_server = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': 'x.x.x.x', 'https': 'x.x.x.x'})
new_opener = urllib2.build_opener(your_squid_server)
urllib2.install_opener(new_opener)
```

Haven't get an environment to check that at the moment though...

**Do the above before importing tweepy to make sure the new opener is in effect**

Comment: tweepy is actually using httplib directly.

Comment: @Martijn Oh wow - okay, hadn't noticed, but now I've looked more - yes - in fact it uses both...

Answer (score 0):

The proxy support in tweepy is severely lacking; there is a [patch available](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/pull/152) that aims to fix that problem.

The patch switches Tweepy from using `httplib` directly to using `urllib2` instead, which means it'd honour the `http_proxy` environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

this is an old question, but hopefully this helps.

https://bitbucket.org/sakito/tweepy provides tweepy with urllib merged into it; the proxy settings works well. there is a little problem with the stream (in my case, at least), but it is usable with a little tweak.