# How Tweepy works behind proxy

Tags: python, proxy, tweepy

I am very new to python So could not figure it out with earlier posts. I am using below sample of code for ingesting twitter streaming, when i am not behind proxy this is working fine, but When i go behind proxy this does not work. will be great help if someone can guide me how to bypass proxy in this code

```
tp = TwitterHandler()
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
stream = tweepy.Stream(auth, tp)

stream.filter(track=FILTER_WORDS_LIST)
```

Comment: Tweepy doesn't seem to have support behind proxy. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13175328/using-tweepy-api-behind-proxy) question for more information.

Comment: It's quite sad that no one seems to care to document how to use the proxy functionality in tweepy because it is such a useful feature.

Answer (score 4):

You can set it inside your code:

```
import os
os.environ['http_proxy'] = 'http://username:password@host:port'
os.environ['https_proxy'] = 'http://username:password@host:port'
```

Answer (score 1):

I was going through this link to get started with tweepy - http://adilmoujahid.com/posts/2014/07/twitter-analytics/

I too got stuck with the proxy problem..Here is how I solved it -

In your Windows terminal type

```
set http_proxy=http://username:password@host:port

set https_proxy=https://username:password@host:port
```

then run the file as given in the link above-

```
python twitter_streaming.py
```

Setting the global proxy environment variables is the key

I hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did to run [tweepy](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy) behind a proxy:

```
import tweepy

class ProxyStream(tweepy.Stream):

    def new_session(self):

        super().new_session() # PY2: super(ProxyStream, self).new_session()
        self.session.proxies = {
            'https': 'http://proxy1:3128',
            'http': 'http://proxy1:3128'
        }
```

Now, by using `ProxyStream` instead of `tweepy.Stream` does the trick:

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler('TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY', 'TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET')
auth.set_access_token('TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN', 'TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET')
stream = ProxyStream(auth, self, async=True)
```

Setting up `HTTPS_PROXY` variable should work, but in some cases, we need a specific configuration for external resources, such as twitter.