# Tweepy twitter api v.2.0

Tags: python, tweepy

Currently I am trying to mask my IP address when accessing the twitter API V2.0, using Tweepy. However I cant find any method on changing my IP address through a proxy in the python code itself. Does anyone have the solution to this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How Tweepy works behind proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36791620/how-tweepy-works-behind-proxy)

Comment: @RJ Adriaansen 
It doesnt, for some reason it still uses my current IP address. I have tried this method
'''
import os
os.environ['http_proxy'] = 'http://username:password@host:port'
os.environ['https_proxy'] = 'http://username:password@host:port' 
'''

Comment: Perhaps an even simpler solution not to expose your own IP is to run your code on google colab

Comment: @RJ Adriaansen 
It doesnt, because I'm trying to interact with the API such as retweet, follow, comment instead of pulling requests

Comment: @RJAdriaansen well im trying to use multiple proxy addresses for multiple accounts

Answer (score 0):

You do this through requests.Session.
Just create a requests.Session, set the proxy parameters in it, and assign the session to the Client object before performing any requests.